# 415 Unsupported Media Type when using Postman and Asp Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Why do I get a status of 415 "Unsupported Media Type" when I use Postman to create a new Item. I get the desired results if I use the GetAll but not when I try to create something. Code is below:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]TodoItem item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.Id }, item);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

default content-type text/plain in postman try to add header

`Content-Type:application/json`
and you are using [FromBody] tag so send your parameters in body